# icon / text size too big in Design View in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, design-view

I'm using visual studio C# and have a weired problem, i closed the IDE and open it in again the next day and now the design view the icons and text become oversized like the screenshot below but when i run the the App the icon/text has normal size

[image]

Even when i open an old project i got an oversized button/text.

I was able to overcome this problem two times by installing an update of the software when it's available. but now the same problem happened but unfortunately there is no software update available.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

I had a 4k screen connected to my computer along with my 2 1080p main screens.

i uplugged the 4k screen calbe and i restarted visual studio and it seems working. the text/button .. are back to normal.
it's weired because the 4K screen is disabled inside my windows OS.